# Dependency non-existent parameter "base_cdn"

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have an annoying error that doesn't let me do any `composer install` or `server:start` or `cache:clear`

I don't understand the error

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]  
  You have requested a non-existent parameter "base_cdn".
```

and so it can't let me do anything.
And I have many other issues such as:

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for gregwar/image v2.0.20 -> satisfiable by gregwar/image[v2.0.20].
    - gregwar/image v2.0.20 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
Problem 2
    - Installation request for gregwar/image-bundle v2.1.3 -> satisfiable by gregwar/image-bundle[v2.1.3].
    - gregwar/image-bundle v2.1.3 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
```

I can't make a composer update as in the project it is forbidden to do (as good practice) but I only can make `composer install`.

So anyway, I'm lost. Anyone got an idea on this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You have requested a non-existent parameter "base_cdn".

This means you are using somewhere in your code a `base_cdn` parameter. You can search it in your project, it will be used surrounded by percent sign - `%base_cdn%`. So, you are using it somewhere but it's not defined anywhere, so all you need to do is to add `base_cdn` parameter to your `parameters.yml` file (in fact you should also add it to your `parameters.yml.dist` file as well)

EDIT: If you have it in your `parameters.yml.dist` already then most probably `composer` will ask you for `base_cdn` value after successfull `composer install` which currently can't be performed because of the `gd` issue. If, for some reason, `composer` will not ask for a value after `composer install` then just copy line with `base_cdn` from `parameters.yml.dist` to `parameters.yml`. Since `parameters.yml` is not stored in version control (or at least should not be stored) all your teammates will have to type in this value after `composer install`

> gregwar/image v2.0.20 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.

This means you are misssing `gd` php extension. To install it you will need to do something like `apt-get install php-gd` depending on what system you are working on.

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)